# JavaScript задача на рекурсию

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

учу JS и решал задачу на рекурсию. Вот кусок кода (правильный и рабочий):

```js
function indexSum(n) {
  n = `${n}`;
  if (n.length === 1) {
    return +n;
  }
  return +n[0] + indexSum(n.slice(1));
}

console.log(indexSum(555555));
```

Объясните, зачем нужна шаблонная строка на второй строчке? Что она делает?

Comment: Преобразование числа в строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Инструкция во второй строке приводит число к строке, то есть преобразует `5555` (число) в `"5555"` (строку).

Далее по тексту встречается обратная операция `+n` и `+n[0]`, которая преобразует `"5"` (строку) в `5` (число).